# Where do I get the key to enter the Winterhold College?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a quest that needs me to go there, but I can't seem to get inside as I need a key.

Talking to some locals in the houses didn't seem to give more information on where I fetch that key, did I miss something that the quest giver might have said me? How do I get that key?

Comment: Have you tried simply joining the College?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Is that possible? I haven't seen anyone ask me...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Speak to Faralda at the entrance:

First, ask her why she's here.

Then ask her if you can enter the college.

When she asks why, your answer will choose which school of magic you join (destructive, etc)

She will ask you to perform a test with a certain spell. You probably don't have the spell yet, so buy it. It's going to be about 30 gold.

Once you buy the spell, if you are roughly level 3 or 4, you cast the spell at the seal on the floor. She will then lead you to the door of the college herself, no key required.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Seems I quit the conversation usually, now that I know which option to take and did it a bit more patiently I finally got into the Winterhold college now. I will award you the bounty once the system allows me... :)

Comment: She won't let me perform a spell or ask me to do a shout. Maybe it's because I'm a Nord but I need to get in there; what do I do?

Answer (score 7):

To enter the college you must become a member. Speak with the NPC (Her name is Faralda) standing at the beginning of the bridge connecting the college to Winterhold and she will explain what you need to do to join the college.

She will ask you to cast a spell at a symbol on the ground. If you can do it, she will admit you to the college.( If you don't know what the symbol looks like then just shoot the ground at the front of the bridge where it looks different.)

The spell she will ask you to cast will be one of the following: Firebolt, Helping Hand, Summon flame Atronach, Fear

Once you're a member, the gates will open for you, no key is needed.

Comment: She doesn't ask me this, what do I do?

Comment: @TomWijsman you need to ask her why she is at the bridge enterance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a Destruction, Illusion, Alteration, or Restoration spell.

You can also just do a shout to show her that you are Dragonborn.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can tell her that you are dragonborn and show her a shout. She opens the gate straight away.

Comment: This is bugged out for me. After she says "I'd be interested to see that" the dialogue ends and I can't talk to her anymore. I also can't kill her or pickpocket her.

Comment: How do I tell her that? The conversation doesn't lead to that...

Comment: I had someone who didn't believe I was dragonborn. I shouted at him to make my point, but the guards didn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Something to keep in mind is don't try going up the stone bridge on your horse, as Faralda will not stop you and ask you the questions necessarily to get into the college.