# Why can't I get inside the College of Winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I get the key to enter the Winterhold College?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35405/where-do-i-get-the-key-to-enter-the-winterhold-college)

I'm on a quest (Under Saarthal), and the quest asked me to go the College of Winterhold. Unfortunately, I can't get inside the college because the front gate is locked and I don't have the key. I have been to the college before and talked to the lady in front of the college.

Answer (score 4):

When you first talked to Faralda, did you give her a magic demonstration?  She should have asked you to cast a spell either on her, or onto the symbol at her feet.  Once you have done so, the locked door will be gone and you will be free to enter the college.  If you do not have the spell she's looking for, she will teach it to you for a cheap price of 30 gold.

It is also possible to by pass her if your speechcraft is high enough.

Comment: Yes, i did that before, but Faralda isn't appearing in front of the college

Comment: @Wafieldn she may have wandered off due to a dragon attack or some such, but if you say you already passed the test and the door is still locked, that must be a glitch, if you are on the PC, just use the console to unlock it.