# Faralda is not outside of the college in winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't get into the College of Winterhold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80031/i-cant-get-into-the-college-of-winterhold)

I am trying to join the college but faralda is not there, I have never talked to her, plus this was my first time at winterhold, someone please.help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Faralda is off doing other things for several reasons. Rather than list all the possibilities here I'm going to tell you to do one of several workarounds.

- Sleep for a week and come back
- Sleep for a month and come back
- Never come back
- Try showing up during the 'workday'
- Try showing up after C.O.B.
- Use console commands to 'summon' her.

Comment: related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41457/why-cant-i-get-inside-the-college-of-winterhold?rq=1

Comment: Close of Business. IE: after the shops close up for the night.

Comment: Okay thanks a ton, I will try these when I get home.